# Issue while trying to post array data along with image

Tags: javascript, jquery

**JQuery code to post array data along with image**

```
var fileUpload = $("[name='Image']").get(0);
var files = fileUpload.files;

var fileData = new FormData();

var Selectedtags = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "wswsw"
}];

fileData.append("Categories", Selectedtags);
fileData.append("Image", files[0]);

$.ajax({
    "type": "post",
    "url": "/some url",
    "data": fileData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(response) {
    }
});
```

**Due to some reasons to shows highlighted payload like below**

[image]

I am able to read the image but category data is blank at server side. Am I doing anything wrong in the js side?

Answer (score 0):

The Content-Type isn't set to application/json. In order to post json data along without changing the Content-Type you would need to stringify the json object.

```js
fileData.append("Categories", JSON.stringify(Selectedtags));
```

And on the server side if you want to use the json object again use:

```js
Selectedtags = JSON.parse(Selectedtags);
```

These functions turns a json object into a string and back with `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Payload has file object as well as array. I am using goland. I can't post it as json or file object won't be able to read, can u suggest?